# Excel : If statement using time

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up something in excel wherein if time is 6 pm (18:00) then N20 (N20 is a web query and the value increases/decreases during random intervals) will copy the cell content/value to O20

Comment: You have now edited out your attempts which may earn you down/close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might actually want to use a workbook_open event to run a sub at the specified time that manages the transfer.

In ThisWorkbook code pane:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "Module1.GetValueAtSixPm"

End Sub
```

In standard module 1 put:

```
Public Sub GetValueAtSixPm()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")   ' <== Change as required
    With ws
        .Range("O20") = .Range("N20")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically, there are 2 cells that are being used
1) N20 
2)  O20

**N20** - gets the value using a web query and updates every 4 min.

what I'm trying to do is, when it is 18:00, the value (value at 6 pm) of N20 is copied to O20

Comment: Will the workbook be open and does the value have to be retained?

Comment: The workbook will be opened the entire time and the specific value at 6 pm is to be retained. N20 may still increase later, but i only want the value to be copied to O20 when it is exact 6 pm

Comment: Ill try it out now.

I have a doubt tho, why did you put the time value as 14:22?

Also in this case, will the value be copied automatically or only when i copy it?

Comment: While manually running the macro, it works. But it doesnt seem to run automatically, it says "Cannot run the macro....."

The macros are enabled in the settings tho